# Could these white fluffy spots on the wood in my attic be be mold?

Tags: attic, mold

I am currently living in Vancouver area, recently I got a leak in my roof but my roofer already fixed it yesterday.

After the day it was repaired  I went up to our attic to check if if everything was OK  and no more leaks but I   noticed this white something (*maybe mold*) growing in some of part of my wood.

I read on the internet that you can kill molds with a bleach solution and wipe it with paper towel? I am not sure if this would be safe to do in my attic.

Is this dangerous that I need to call professional immediately?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m 99% sure this is mildew/mold caused by the high humidity level in leaky attic.  Hopefully the moisture levels will come down now that the leak is fixed.

It would be wise to spray the areas with a non chlorine mold killer like [Concrobium](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Concrobium-128-fl-oz-Liquid-Mold-Remover/1001073964)

For the next few weeks check humidity levels in the attic.  If they remain high you may need to ventilate the attic better.

Comment: I havent use Concrobium before, is it safe? Should I just spray it on wood directly and wife it with paper towel afterwards?

Comment: Yes it is safe and no obnoxious chlorine odor. Wiping is not necessary

Comment: ok ill buy one tomorrow with this stuff thank you.. 

What should be the humidity level in the attic, around what percent?

Comment: I saw this on homedepot, Aside from the spray do you think I can put this on my attic while I havent put a fix for the ventilation?

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/concrobium-moisture-grabbers-xl/1000838196

Comment: [This site](https://www.jcarnesroofing.com/blog/causes-and-solutions-for-excessive-moisture-in-attics) says 30-50% humidity level should be maintained

Comment: Thank @kris ill definitely check what's the humidity level in my attic. I think I got free stuff like the humidity checker that I got from previous seminar event I attended..

Comment: @Kris The issue below that range isn’t one of potential structural problems, it’s a matter of comfort. Most humans have issues with a %RH more than about 20-30 off of what the yearly average is where they live, so unless you live in a desert, anything less than roughly 30%RH risks being uncomfortable (there are other reasons to not want it too low though, including reducing buildup of static electricity).

Comment: @Kris hmm I think you mistakenly read that I did the last comment.. Anyways I already went to our attic and spray the Concrobium. Based on the instruction I should it it overnight. So let you know what will happy

Comment: @Hawk   Yes I did misread.  Sorry

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn   It’s an attic no one living in the space

Answer (score 4):

I'd put on a N95 mask.  Take a bucket of water with some bleach and a dish sponge.  Scrub the surface of the wood down with the bleach solution.  Let it dry, once dry I'd use a white vinegar spray to spray the affected wood, let it dry.  If it looks good then you can either leave it or paint it with a mold encapsulating primer/paint like extreme stain block.

I wouldn't worry too much about the mold in general as warmer lower density air moves up and is pulled into the attic.  Air that is already in the attic is unlikely to come into your living space.  Mold isn't good for you but varies based on exposure, species and sensitivity.  Mold spores exist in fresh outside air and it grows naturally outside so even fresh air will have a spore count to it.  The more toxic species of mold typically have a black look - even then something of this size you should be able to self remediate.

You should get a hygrometer and find the RH of that attic it should be below 60% RH.  You can do a quick check of square footage of attic and count how many air vents you have - most attic are under vented.  You want soffit intake venting and ridge or high output venting.  You should ensure that the insulation that is in your attic has not clogged the soffit vents.

Comment: Actually I noticed some insulation are clogged to the side of my roof prevent some air flowing air inside the roof. Maybe 3-5 out of 16 holes are clogged.. Is it safe to use bleach on wood I read that its just add moisture to the wood

Comment: I want to cleat it but the side of my roof is so stiff that only a long stick can reach and get to it. Do you have any tips on how can I clear it out?

Comment: vacuum with a long attachment can suck out that insulation or you can use a leaf rake.  that wood already has enough water i wouldn't worry about adding a little more bleach water at this point.  if it was drywall i wouldn't use bleach water but surface mold on wood is fine.

Comment: Totally agree with the mask.  I breathed something in from a ceiling space and ended up hospitalised with a lung infection.  Warm, damp and dark is a perfect breeding ground for badness.   A better tool than a bucket might be a garden pressure sprayer with a wand, to help OP get further out with less risk.

Comment: Thank you so much with overwhelming help guy really appreciate it. Its Christmas day today so all your comments super helpful hope you have all wonderful holiday

Comment: @Criggie sorry to hear about that, just curious how much exposure did you get that you ended up in hospital? Just wanted to make sure that I am doing as safe as possible I dont want to cause lung infection to other people at my house specially my baby

Comment: @Hawk it was 11 years ago, but I spent an hour up there checking things out after an earthquake, like the HW cylinder.  Breathing the disturbed dust did it.  A lung/chest infection is not contageous, but you'll bring dust down on your overalls/gloves/etc when you descend the ladder.   Make an effort to contain all the dust, change immediately in that spot, and then clean up with a vacuum, and air the house, ie get a breeze flowing through.  Perhaps do all this when the baby is out of the house for a day.  Could be a good separate question about "how to keep house safe/clean when doing XYZ"

Comment: @Criggie not sure if you still remember but is this the same color as this one that infect your lungs? Just wanted to make sure doing something with that I took all safety.. Its doesnt look like black molds, I read black molds are the super serious ones

Comment: The interior window in my bedroom was the color of your wood.  I hadn't moved the curtain in a year and dust had gathered, water had condensed and mold had eaten the dust/grown on top of the painted surface.  I used bleach water with dish scrub sponge and it looks pretty good today.  I had a mask.  It is the spores of the mold that are inhalation hazards if you have a bleach spray bottle and you spray before you wipe spores shouldn't be put into the air.  If you let the mold dry out and try to clean it dry that would the worst.

Comment: @hawk sorry - it was dark and dusty up there and I do not recall seeing what colour it was before I disturbed it.   Just wear a good filter mask, not a cheap paper one.  You may be able to hire one, they're expensive.

Comment: @Criggie thanks.. yup I am using N95 everytime I got up on the attic just to be safe. Are you referring to KN95, they are cheaper version made in China

Comment: @Hawk good work - I meant that a N95 mask is your minimum for health.  If I had one, a respirator would be more reassuring and comfortable.   But KN95 vs N95 are pretty close.  https://smartairfilters.com/en/blog/whats-the-difference-between-n95-and-kn95-masks/  suggests they're almost the same so I wouldn't stress over KN vs N.